# Text keeps blinking in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

so I am making a code where there is a character(A rectangle) and and Balloon(A circle) and the character has to catch the balloons before it hits the ground. Everything worked fine until I tried making the game look a little better and used the blit function to add an image. For some reason my text keeps buffering now.

Code:

```
import random
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

#Variables
white = (255, 255, 255)
blue = (70,130,180)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)
x = 400
y = 450
score = 0
cooly = 100
randomx = random.randint(100,800)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
#screen stuff
screenwidth = 800
screenheight = 600

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screenwidth, screenheight))
pygame.display.set_caption("Balloon Game!")
#end of screen stuff

#Initializing font
def show_text(msg, x, y, color,size): 
   fontobj= pygame.font.SysFont("freesans", size)
   msgobj = fontobj.render(msg,False,color)
   screen.blit(msgobj,(x, y))
#Game loop
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
    # Draw Character
    screen.fill(blue)
    character = pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, (x, y, 60, 60))
    #End of Drawing Character

    #Draw Balloons
    balloon = pygame.draw.circle(screen, (black), (randomx, cooly), 30, 30)
    cooly = cooly + 2
    # Making Arrow Keys
    keyPressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keyPressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        x -= 3
    if keyPressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        x += 3

    #Drawing Cool Stuff
    Cloud = pygame.image.load('Cloud.png')
    screen.blit(Cloud,(100,75))
    pygame.display.update()
    
    #End of making arrow keys
    show_text("Score:",130,0,black,50)
    show_text(str(score),250,0,black,50)

    #Collision
    if balloon.colliderect(character):
        randomx = random.randint(100,800)
        cooly = 100
        score = score + 1
    #end of collision

    #Ending
    if cooly >= 600:
        screen.fill(blue)
        show_text("Game Over!", 200, 250, black, 100)
        show_text("Score :", 200, 350, black, 75)
        show_text(str(score), 400, 350, black, 75)
    #Polishing
    if score == score + 5:
            cooly += 1
            x += 3
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(250)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "text keeps buffering"?

Comment: it like blinks by going invisible then visible again

Comment: Remove `pygame.display.update()` from the middle of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by multiple calls to [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update). An update of the display at the end of the application loop is sufficient. Multiple calls to `pygame.display.update()` or `pygame.display.flip()` cause flickering.

Remove all calls to `pygame.display.update()` from your code, but call it once at the end of the application loop.

Do not create the font object and do not load the images in the application loop. This are very expensive operatios, because the filed have to be read and interpreted:

```py
fontobj= pygame.font.SysFont("freesans", size)      #<-- INSERT

def show_text(msg, x, y, color,size): 
   # fontobj= pygame.font.SysFont("freesans", size)  <-- DELET
   msgobj = fontobj.render(msg,False,color)
   screen.blit(msgobj,(x, y))

Cloud = pygame.image.load('Cloud.png')              #<-- INSERT

# [...]
while True:
    # [...]

    # Cloud = pygame.image.load('Cloud.png')        <-- DELETE
    screen.blit(Cloud,(100,75))
    # pygame.display.update()                       <-- DELETE

    # [...]

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(250)
```

Comment: yes I was going to accept it I still need to wait 3 minutes

Comment: @RavishankarD Thank you. You're welcome.